# Scrape data from a socket connection

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, socket.io

I've been trying to scrape data from a website that uses socket.io for live updates. It would be very handy if this is possible.

Most of the work performed by the socket layer is in sending and receiving data. The socket layer itself explicitly refrains from imposing any structure on data transmitted or received through sockets.

I'm trying to get live updates from the website [https://www.coinscrash.com/](https://coinscrash.com). However I tried the following code and wouldn't get any updates other than a connection:

```js
var io = require("socket.io-client");
var socket = io("https://www.coinscrash.com");

socket.on("connect", function () {
  console.log(true);
});

socket.on("msg", function (data) {
  console.log("chat message");
});

socket.on("disconnect", function () {
  console.log(false);
});

socket
  .on("error", (err) => console.log(err))
  .on("connect_error", (err) => console.log(err));
```

Am I doing something wrong or is this just not possible?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that your method of scraping works. You have made a lot of baseless assumptions in your code. I will explain the method that I have used to gather information about the socket connection and leave the rest to you. I also tried to rectify your mistakes but without success.

### Inspecting packets

By opening the Network and Application tab on Chrome Dev Tools for `https://coinscrash.com/play`, we can obtain a lot of information about the socket connection:

- The server for the socket connection has URL https://game.coinscrash.com/socket.io/.
- The client of the socket  connection has URL https://coinscrash.com/.
- The request URL has some parameters `EIO`, `transport`, `t`, and `sid`:

```
https://game.coinscrash.com/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=OoRA8bm&sid=YTATw0ot9MvDA542ABdY
```

- Cookies are involved in this connection:
  [image]
- The transport type is polling:

[image]

### Inspecting socket event names from website code

From the Sources tab of Chrome Dev Tools, we can obtain some information from `main-new-a35c0ce7.js`:

- The client emits a `ping` event and expects a `pong` event from server within some delay:
  [image]

### Why your code does not work

```js
var socket = io('https://www.coinscrash.com')
```

There is nothing to connect to at `https://www.coinscrash.com`. As noted previously, the server for the socket connection has URL https://game.coinscrash.com/socket.io/.

Assuming you somehow managed to connect to the server, your code will still not work because the event name `msg` is incorrect:

```
socket.on('msg', function(data) {
console.log('chat message');
});
```

The client should be expecting a `pong` event.

### My failed attempt

First I am running the code on a HTTP server to continuously monitor the socket connection. Without the server, your code will run once and end.

```js
// setup server
const http = require("node:http");
const hostname = "127.0.0.1";
const port = 3000;
const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
  res.statusCode = 200;
  res.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain");
  res.end("Hello World\n");
});
server.listen(port, hostname, () => {
  console.log(`Server running at http://${hostname}:${port}/`);
});

const BACKEND_URL = "https://game.coinscrash.com/socket.io/";

const { io } = require("socket.io-client");
const socket = io(BACKEND_URL, {
  reconnectionDelayMax: 10000,
  autoConnect: false,
  transports: ["polling", "websocket"],
  withCredentials: true, // includes cookies in socket
});

// Adds a listener that will be fired when any event is emitted.
socket.on("connect", () => {
  console.log(socket.id);
});

// Adds a listener that will be fired when any event is emitted.
socket.onAny((eventName, ...args) => {
  console.log(eventName);
});
```

My code still fails to connect to the socket service most probably because this code does not send the required cookies to coinscrash server.

### Final thoughts

Connecting directly to the socket service is not straightforward in this case because there is probably some session-based authentication (using cookies) taking place on the coinscrash server. Since you're using a basic NodeJS environment, you will not be able to pass the authentication.

Moreover, coincrash most proabably has the socket configured to run only on their domain name so even if you clone their frontend website and run it on localhost for example, the socket connection will not succeed.